# How to count how many words of a list are in each entry of another list on Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, text, count

I have two lists,

In the first list "List1" my entries are a text (many words) for example

```python
[My house is red, The dog is black, The table is small, The wind is cold]
```

on the other list "List2" each entry corresponds to a word

```python
[house, red, wind, small, big, dog, cat, fox, car]
```

I want to count how many words from List2 are also in List1 for each entry

the result could be a new list "List3"

```python
[2, 1, 1, 1]
```

I thought about using count: `List1.count(List2)`, but it accept only values not another list

I thought about using a for loop

```python
List 3 = []

for w in List2:
    if w in List1:
      List3 = 1
    else:
      List3 = List3[w] + 1
```

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment where the goal is to learn some basic concepts such as looping.  Submit some formatted code to show some progress and ask something more specific after you make some progress.

Comment: What's the issue with using a for loop that you ran into? It looks like the question just stops prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

```
List1 = ["My house is red", "The dog is black", "The table is small", "The wind is cold"]
List2 = ["house", "red", "wind", "small", "big", "dog", "cat", "fox", "car"]

List3 = []

for entry in List1:
    words_in_entry = entry.split()  # Split the entry into individual words
    count = 0  # Initialize the count for the current entry
    for word in List2:
        if word in words_in_entry:
            count += 1
    List3.append(count)

print(List3)
```

In this Code it iterate through each entry in List1, split the entry into individual words, and then check how many words from List2 are present in that entry. The count for each entry is stored then in List 3. I guess this is what you looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List1 = ["My house is red", "The dog is black", "The table is small", "The wind is cold"]
List2 = ["house", "red", "wind", "small", "big", "dog", "cat", "fox", "car"]

List3 = []

for i in List1:
    list1_words = i.split()  
    count = sum(1 for word in list1_words if word in List2)  
    List3.append(count)

print(List3)
```

output:-

```
[2, 1, 1, 1]
```

The code splits each entry in `List1` into words and then counts how many of those words are present in `List2`. The counts are appended to `List3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() inside a list comprehension over the split strings of list 1.  The sum, for each item of list1 will count instances of words that are present in list2:

```
list1 = ["My house is red", "The dog is black", 
         "The table is small", "The wind is cold"]
list2 = ["house", "red", "wind", "small", "big", "dog", "cat", "fox", "car"]

list3 = [sum(w1 in list2 for w1 in s1) for s1 in map(str.split,list1)]

print(list3) # [2, 1, 1, 1]
```